# Error:Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea with Gradle 5.1.1.I want to refresh a Gradle project but when I refresh the project I receive an error:

Error:Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.9. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5?

Comment: yess, thats mentioned in his question

Comment: how about if i'm using eclipse?

Comment: If using Eclipse upgrade to version 2019-03 enterprise developer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to upgrade your Intellij Idea. I meet the same error, and I upgrade my version to 2019. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is old, which is not suitable to your Gradle. I uninstall the compiler and reinstall the newest version. The problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

([IntelliJ IDEA uses the Tooling API for importing your Gradle project and running](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html)

maybe your IDEA's Tooling API plugin's version is too lower.

how to upgrade it is : [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-change-gradle-tooling-api-version/25721)